# MSBuild Batch File - Custom Task Parameter

Tags: batch-file, msbuild, msbuild-task, msbuild-propertygroup

How can I access custom parameter in my MSBuild?

For example, this is a call:

```
 msbuild.exe /t:CustomTask /p:CustomParameterName="Some Value Here"
```

And I want to access in task like this:

```
<Target Name="CustomTask">  
  <PropertyGroup>
    <CustomParameterName>NONE</CustomParameterName>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Message Text="Parameter Value: $(CustomParameterName)" Importance="high" />
</task>
```

...or anyhow, just like a variable sent trough the batch file while I'm calling MSBuild.exe

Answer (score 0):

Solved the issue:

`<PropertyGroup>
    <CustomParameterName>NONE</CustomParameterName>
</PropertyGroup>`

This need to be defined outside of task.